# How to call the real save method at the Repository which is MockBean?

Tags: mockito, repository

I have a Repository which is annotated with @MockBean, But I want to call the real save function to save the Entity, However, Even if I use CALLS_REAL_METHODS it still doesn't work, just like the code below:

```java
@SpringBootTest
class SchoolTest {
  @MockBean StudentRepository studentRepository;
  
  @Test
  void studentRepository_throwConstraintViolationException_ifDuplicate() {
    studentRepository = mock(StudentRepository.class, CALLS_REAL_METHODS);

    Student student = new Student(12306L, "JinPing");
    studentRepository.save(student);

    Student student2 = new Student(12306L, "JinPing");

    assertThrows(ConstraintViolationException.class, ()-> studentRepository.save(student2));
  }
}
```

And this is the Repository

```java
@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Long> {
}
```

This is the Student entity

```java
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student {
  @Id private Long id;

  private String name;
}
```

Comment: If all you want is to call a real method, why bother with the mock? Autowire the real repository instead.

Comment: Ye, That can do it, But my other tests need the mock, So I have to keep it as a MockBean.

Comment: `@SpyBean` is what you're asking for but seems like you're mixing unit and integration tests that are usually better separate

Comment: Ye,  But  I think SpyBean can't be used at @Repository.